# unable to upload files in django through web forms

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a django website similar to that of Udemy or Coursera. I am trying to implement a feature that lets users add courses.

Here is my view for adding the course:

```
def create_course(request):
    form = CreateCourseForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateCourseForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_course = form.save(commit=False)
            new_course.instructor = request.user
            new_course.save()
            return redirect('home')
    return render(request, 'courses/create.html',{'form':form})
```

Here is my form:

```
class CreateCourseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Course
        fields = ('name','video','description','category',)
```

My course model:

```
class Course(models.Model): 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    instructor = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    video = models.FileField(upload_to='videos/')
    description = models.TextField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

And finally my web form:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Create a Course</h1>
<hr>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|crispy }}
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" type="submit">Create Course</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

The issue i am facing is that when i try to create a course, the video field shows an error "This field is required" even when I have uploaded a video.

I tried researching a bit and found out that adding `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to the form was required, but even adding that didn't solve my problem

Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass `request.POST` *and* `request.FILES` to the form, so:

```
def create_course(request):
    form = CreateCourseForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        #                             add request.FILES ↓
        form = CreateCourseForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        # …
    return render(request, 'courses/create.html',{'form':form})
```

If you only pass `request.POST`, you are only passing the items of the form that are *not* file uploads. This then will indeed add an error to the form fields of these files, saying that the form requires data for these fields.

Answer (score 0):

as willem told you have to request file in you form like this

```
def create_course(request):
    form = CreateCourseForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateCourseForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_course = form.save(commit=False)
            new_course.instructor = request.user
            new_course.save()
            return redirect('home')
    return render(request, 'courses/create.html',{'form':form})
```

but i think you have to know one more you don't have to pass / in while telling django where to upload that file

```
class Course(models.Model): 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    instructor = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    video = models.FileField(upload_to='videos')
    description = models.TextField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

offcourse willem answer will solve your problem but you will see in your media folder a new folder name videos/ got created where you file is storing instead of your actual folder becuase you are telling django to upload that file in folder name vedios/ and if django doesn't find that folder it will create that folder with that name and then stat uploading it

Comment: Thanks for the extra info, appreciate it :)